# Asp Net Core MVC - Criar Formulário com Várias

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp, identity

É a primeira vez que faço uma pergunta, e estou me acostumando com a página, então me perdoem caso eu erre em alguma regra.

Sou novo no Asp Net Core MVC e estou apanhando muito para entender algumas coisas.
A que está me impedindo de continuar meu trabalho da forma que gostaria, creio que seja na hora de linkar as tabelas criadas ao registro principal.

Entidade Ocorrencia (principal)

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID da Ocorrência")]
    public int OcorrenciaID { get; set; }
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
```

Entidade Endereco

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID do Endereço")]
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Logradouro")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório!")]
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório!")]
    public int TipoID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
    public Tipo Tipo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório!")]
    public int BairroID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
    public Bairro Bairro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ocorrências")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencias { get; set; }
```

Entidade Bairro

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID do Bairro")]
    public int BairroID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório!")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Digite entre 5 e 50 caracteres!")]
    public string DescBairro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public int CidadeID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public Cidade Cidade { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereços")]
    public ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
```

Entidade Tipo

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID do Tipo")]
    public int TipoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório!")]
    public string DescTipo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Selecionado")]
    public bool Assinado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string DescOutros { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereços")]
    public ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
```

CONTROLLER

public IActionResult Create()

```
    {            
        PopularBairroDDL();
        PopularTiposDDL();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("OcorrenciaID,NumOcorrencia,NumGerado,EnderecoID,BairroID,TipoID")]
    Ocorrencia ocorrencia, Endereco endereco)
    {
        Endereco end = new Endereco
        {
            BairroID = endereco.BairroID,
            TipoID = endereco.TipoID
        };
        ocorrencia.Endereco = end;
        ocorrencia.EnderecoID = end.EnderecoID;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(ocorrencia);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        PopularBairroDDL(ocorrencia);
        PopularTiposDDL(ocorrencia);
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
```

Minha dúvida se baseia principalmente no momento de efetuar a gravação. Pois pelo que entendi, o Entity faz tudo sozinho, ela já relaciona os campos com as tabelas e ao gravar já colocar as ID's corretamente nas tabelas, desde que direcionadas corretamente nos objetos. Porém ao debugar, vejo que ao passar pelo método Get, sempre o Endereco vem com ID = 0. Tentei algumas coisas mas nunca passa uma ID, o que é estranho, já que está com o campo identity e gera sozinho o id.
Poderiam me dar uma luz por favor, agradeceria muito.
abraço.

Comment: Falta algumas informações para entender o fluxo que sua aplicação tem, mas tente marcar a propriedade Endereco da classe Ocorrencia como virtual

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer o seguinte mude

```
  Endereco end = new Endereco
    {
        BairroID = endereco.BairroID,
        TipoID = endereco.TipoID
    };
    ocorrencia.Endereco = end;
    ocorrencia.EnderecoID = end.EnderecoID;
```

para

```
    Endereco end = new Endereco
    {
        BairroID = endereco.BairroID,
        TipoID = endereco.TipoID
    };
    _context.Add(end);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    ocorrencia.Endereco = end;
    ocorrencia.EnderecoID = end.EnderecoID;
```

Isso acontecia em versões no ASP.NET MVC mas no .NET CORE isto não acontece.

Nao é indicado você utilizar a inserção direta pelo entityframework, devido a performace.

Pesquise sobre o Dapper, a performace fica muito melhor.

Comment: Vou tentar. Obrigado.

Comment: @LeandroRuchido funcionou?